# How can I tell Python to look for an element only if it exists?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape information from supermarket products but taking into account that some of the info (the origin of the product) isn't always available.

I am trying to iterate over a dataframe of links of a supermarket. From each of them, I want to get some information. However, the origin of the products isn't always available. I don't know how to make Python look for 'origin' only when it is available. I've tried the following code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

dir = ''
file = 'data.xlsx'
sheetname="Hoja1"
# create and write headers to a list 
rows = []
rows.append(['Brand', 'Product', 'Product_Number', 'Gross_Weight', 'Origin'])
# Change working directory: 
os.chdir(dir)
# Retrieve current working directory ('cwd'):
cwd = os.getcwd()
cwd

# Load spreadsheet:
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
# Load a sheet into a DataFrame by name: df1
df = xl.parse(sheetname)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # specify the url
    urlpage =  row['link']
    #print(urlpage)
    # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)
    # parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    # find results within table
    results = soup.find_all('dl', attrs={'class': 'des_info clearfix'})
    #print('Number of results', len(results))
    for result in results:
        # find all columns per result
        data = result.find_all('dd')
        # check that columns have data 
        if len(data) == 0: 
            continue
    
        # write columns to variables
        brand = data[0].getText()
        product = data[1].getText()
        number = data[2].getText()
        weight = data[3].getText()
        if data[4].getText() == None:
            origin = 0
        else:
            origin = data[4].getText()
   
        # write each result to rows
        rows.append([brand, product, number, weight, origin])
```

I get the following error:

```
if data[4].getText() == None:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I would like to get all the data ordered in a list and, if the origin isn't available for one item, a zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `try` statement:

```
    # write columns to variables
    brand = data[0].getText()
    product = data[1].getText()
    number = data[2].getText()
    weight = data[3].getText()
    try:
        origin = data[4].getText()
    except:
        origin = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use len of data

```
if len(data) >= 4:
    #do something
else:
   #do something else
```

Comment: >= 5 I think you meant.